# Back Button With Javascript

Tags: javascript

when i hit back button in browser it should navigate to desired location,

but the code written below works for all the buttons including the 'form' buttons

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
       location.replace('http://www.google.com');
       return "This session is expired and the history altered.";
    }
```

how i can restrict this functionalty to browsers back button alone

thanks

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

Tampering with history is not allowed in the browsers due to privacy & security reasons. Due to this, you won't be able to do this.